# Authenticate to Trello API

Tags: php, trello

i'm trying from my website to invite person via email to Trello with their API. Here is the [API reference](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/organization#put-1-organizations-idorg-or-name-members). When I try to invite a user the plain replay is "invalid key".
Here is my function:

```
public function inviteEmployeeToTrello ($email, $name, $isAdmin)
{
    // valid organazation id
    $organazationTrelloID = '';
    // auth token from trello
    $trelloAuthToken = '';
    $trelloInviteUrl = 'https://trello.com/1/organizations/'.$organazationTrelloID.'/members';

    if ($isAdmin == 1)
    {
        $type = 'admin';
    }
    else
    {
        $type = 'normal';
    }

    $fields = array(
        'fullName' => $name,
        'email' => $email,
        'type' => $type,
        'token' => $trelloAuthToken
    );

    // open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set the url, number of PUT vars, PUT data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $trelloInviteUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // exec
    $replyRaw = curl_exec($ch);
    $reply = json_decode($replyRaw, true);

    // close connection
    curl_close($ch);

    dd($replyRaw);
}
```

I've also inserted 
     script src="https://api.trello.com/1/client.js?key=myTrelloKey">
I'd be glad if you could give me some suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Edit:
I've also inserted
script src="https://api.trello.com/1/client.js?key=5d222c8fdc009236f0c95e0d03b57785"
I'd be glad if you could give me some suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to dump `$ch` you may send the json in a wrong way

Comment: You don't send your application key `key` with your request.

Comment: https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/organization#get-1-organizations-idorg-or-name-members

Comment: i just removed it in the post

Comment: when i dd($ch) returns Unknown resource @6